# Accessing key-value on FLASK/JINJA

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, key, jinja2

So my back-end is delivering this to the front:

```
 "results": [
        {
            "id": 166740,
            "usuario": {
                "id": 64600,
            "operations": [
                {
                    "value": 1000.0,
                    "data": "20/04/2022 18:06",
                    "status": "1",
                    "expired": true,
                },
                {
                    "value": 1000.0,
                    "data": "20/04/2022 18:17",
                    "status": "6",
                    "expired": false,
             
                }
           ]}
```

How can I loop through it and acccess expired and status? I started with:

```
 <script id="tpl__report_apoios" type="text/x-jsrender">

                {% raw %}
                {^{for results}}
```

on my flask app but anything after that wont work

Comment: do you send it with `render_template(..., results)` or you get it using JavaScript/AJAX? First can use normal loop, second need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
{% for result in results %}
{% result.status %}
{% result.expired %}
```